# How to write a query where the between statement is a select statement from the same table-MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query where I want to write

```
select * from my_table where updated_date is >= '19/20/12' AND <=max(updated_date)
```

My table goes like this:

```
field1| updated_date | field3
```

So I want all the records from my_table where the max value from the updated_date field is >='19/20/12'

However when I run my command, its says invalid use of group function. I am new to sql and was wondering if anyone had any ideas or suggestions to solve this?

Comment: remove the MAX function. It is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, the MAX() function is breaking your query, try `WHERE updated_date >= '19/20/12'`

Comment: Please View edits. I want to get the max updated date in the paramter part of the query

Comment: Then try `SELECT MAX(updated_date) FROM your_table_name WHERE updated_date >= '19/20/12'`  **BTW** this would be the same as just `SELECT MAX(updated_date) FROM your_table_name` because the condition returns the highest values for `updated_date`

Comment: I dont think you guys get what I am trying to do. I need all the records in the table that is between the latest updated_date value and between '19/20/12'

Comment: It is a transactional table. And I am trying to do incremntal loads. So, I need to select  all columns that are between the last entry date (which is the max updated_date field) and '19/20/12'

Comment: Also take some time to read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers/251399#251399 It seems that you have long forgotten how to accept an answer.

Comment: You didnt answer my question correclty

Comment: @Coder123 it seems that your last 18 questions were not answered correctly, right? Maybe you should rethink about how to post questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments, It seems you need below -

```
select *
from my_table
where updated_date between '19/20/12' AND (SELECT max(updated_date) FROM my_table)
```

Or

```
select *
from my_table
where updated_date >= '19/20/12' AND updated_date <= (SELECT max(updated_date) FROM my_table)
```

As all others are commenting, Using `updated_date <= max(updated_date)` is superflous condition coz whatever value you choose, it would always be less than or equals the maximum of the column.

Comment: It is giving me the error of:  Ibnvalid use of group function

Answer (score 0):

If you want *rows* with a date later than the given date, then use:

```
select *
from my_table
where updated_date is >= '2019-12-20';
```

`MAX()` is an aggregation function and it does not belong in the `WHERE` clause.  If you needed to filter by it, then you would have a `GROUP BY` and would use a `HAVING` clause.  However, it does not seem necessary.

Comment: It greater than that date but less than the max updated_date. That query wont work.

Comment: I dont think you guys get what I am trying to do. I need all the records in the table that is between the latest updated_date value and between '19/20/12'

Comment: @Coder123 . . . Your code has `<= max(updated_date)`.  That is a superfluous condition.  All values are `<=` the maximum.